# Masking labels for Checkboxes - The correct way?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am aware that we can create customised checkboxes using `<label for="#checkbox_id">` using the `for` attribute and referencing the input's `id`.

I need to know which would be the best way to hide the background checkbox tag i.e, `<input type="checkbox" class="masked-input" id="checkbox_id"/>`

I'm currently using `.masked-input{display: none;}` .No issues for me so far.

But I have seen in many webpages, they don't use the `display:none` property.

Instead they use

```
.checkbox{
height: 0;
width: 0;
border: 0;
overflow: hidden;
visibility: hidden;
}
```

Why wouldn't they just use `display:none;` and keep this simple? Or am I missing something or doing it the wrong way?

Comment: Can you add your HTML code here??

Comment: @Viira, he asked for a clarification, i think no need to post code here.

Comment: If dispaly:none css is used then it would create issues for developer sometimes for this reason it would be great to use opacity:0 and above css

Comment: display: none also makes them inaccessible via keyboard tab. They can no longer be focussed hence can't be selected via keyboard. So its better to avoid display:none; as it is bad from accessibility point of view

Comment: is there any class named checkbox there?

Comment: @NanditaAroraSharma Yes. I did not think about keyboard users. Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**User Accessibility Issue:**

Its a very straight forward question. You should use

```
.checkbox{
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  border: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

or

```
.checkbox{
   opacity: 0; 
}
```

because if you use `display: none;` it will be hard to access by the user. For instance if the user is trying to access the checkbox by pressing the tab key, the checkbox with the display none property will get skipped from the focus.

In our example below, the second checkbox property is set to `display: none;` and other two checkboxes are set with `opacity: 0;` you can see the focus by pressing tab key and  how the second checkbox is getting skipped.

```css
.styled-checkbox {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
}

#styled-checkbox-2{
  display: none;
}

.styled-checkbox + label {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0;
}
.styled-checkbox + label:before {
  content: '';
  margin-right: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: text-top;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: white;
}
.styled-checkbox:hover + label:before {
  background: #f35429;
}
.styled-checkbox:focus + label:before {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}
.styled-checkbox:checked + label:before {
  background: #f35429;
}
.styled-checkbox:disabled + label {
  color: #b8b8b8;
  cursor: auto;
}
.styled-checkbox:disabled + label:before {
  box-shadow: none;
  background: #ddd;
}
.styled-checkbox:checked + label:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 5px;
  top: 9px;
  background: white;
  width: 2px;
  height: 2px;
  box-shadow: 2px 0 0 white, 4px 0 0 white, 4px -2px 0 white, 4px -4px 0 white, 4px -6px 0 white, 4px -8px 0 white;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
          transform: rotate(45deg);
}

html {
  background: lightgray;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
}

.unstyled {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

li {
  margin: 20px 0;
}

.centered {
  width: 300px;
  margin: auto;
}

.title {
  text-align: center;
  color: #4571ec;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="title">Pure CSS Custom Checkboxes</h1>

<ul class="unstyled centered">
  <li>
    <input class="styled-checkbox" id="styled-checkbox-1" type="checkbox" value="value1">
    <label for="styled-checkbox-1">Checkbox</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input class="styled-checkbox" id="styled-checkbox-2" type="checkbox" value="value2">
    <label for="styled-checkbox-2">CSS Only</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input class="styled-checkbox" id="styled-checkbox-3" type="checkbox" value="value4">
    <label for="styled-checkbox-3">Fourth option</label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Cannot access using keyboard. I did not think of that. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

The code you use is often used when there is a custom styled checkbox. They hide the original checkbox and display a custom one instead. In order to still keep the functionality they only hide the checkbox.

If you use `display: none` the complete checkbox will be removed from the DOM, making it impossible to click.

As https://kyusuf.com/post/completely-css-custom-checkbox-radio-buttons-and-select-boxes states:

> Note that we are hiding the input with z-index: -1; and opacity: 0; -
>   using display: none; or visibility: hidden; would stop the inputs
>   functioning correctly. Onto the .control__indicator - this is what we
>   will style to look like checkboxes/radio buttons.